# C# XML fail importing

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to import an xml file to a c# data grid view. But whenever I use .SelectNodes none of the tags are getting read into my xmlnodelist. Whenever I run a debug on the code and step through the code when it gets to the first foreach statement it immediately leaves the statement, I assume because nothing is inside the xmlnodelist. This is what I have so far. Please help. Thanks in advance

```
namespace DesktopApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int currRow = 0,currCell =0;
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string fileType = ofd.FileName;
                XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xDoc.Load(fileType);
                XmlNode root = xDoc.DocumentElement;

                XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);
                nsmgr.AddNamespace("df", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
                nsmgr.AddNamespace("i", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");


                XmlNodeList listOfEmployees = root.SelectNodes("descendant::Employee",nsmgr);

                foreach (XmlNode employee in listOfEmployees)
                {
                    foreach (XmlNode characteristic in employee)
                    {
                        if (characteristic.InnerText != null)
                        {
                            dataGridView1.Rows[currRow].Cells[currCell].Value = characteristic.InnerText;
                        }
                        currRow++;
                        currCell++;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
    <ImportEmployees xmlns="http://m3as.com/SPDS" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <siteCode>AMH929</siteCode>
        <employees>
            <Employee>
                <EmployeeCode>10444</EmployeeCode>
                <HomeHourlyRate>11</HomeHourlyRate>
                <FirstName>John|Doe</FirstName>
                <LastName />
                <MiddleInitial />
                <Gender>M</Gender>
                <DateOfBirth>20000318</DateOfBirth>
                <ClockNo>10444</ClockNo>
                <DateOfHire>20150318</DateOfHire>
                <EffectiveDate>20160218</EffectiveDate>
                <Address>0000 W MAGNOLIA STREET</Address>
                <Address2 />
                <City>VALDOSTA</City>
                <State>GA</State>
                <Country />
                <PostalCode>12345</PostalCode>
                <EmployeeStatus>A</EmployeeStatus>
                <EmployeeType>Regular</EmployeeType>
                <FullTimePartTime>FT</FullTimePartTime>
                <HrlySlryNonExemptFluc1>Hourly</HrlySlryNonExemptFluc1>
                <PayGroup>0101</PayGroup>
                <ReviewDate />
                <PhoneNumber>1234567890</PhoneNumber>

            </Employee>
        </employees>
    </ImportEmployees>
</s:Body>
```

Comment: I'm not getting an error because the build finishes, The problem is when I try to import the xml file it imports nothing

Comment: I get an error in your XML while trying to cast it to c# class objects.

Answer (score 3):

Your namespace declarations look a bit odd. This one works for me:

```
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("spds", "http://m3as.com/SPDS");

var listOfEmployees = root.SelectNodes("//spds:Employee", nsmgr);
```

Comment: Thanks this works! I'm a bit new to importing xml files. I was just going based of what I saw from some documents.

Answer (score 1):

Try xml linq and put data into a DataTable before loading DGV

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication18
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            button1.Click += new EventHandler(openToolStripMenuItem_Click);
        }
        private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Text", typeof(string));

            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string fileType = ofd.FileName;
                XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(fileType);

                Boolean first = true;
                foreach (XElement employee in xDoc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Employee"))
                {
                    if (first)
                    {
                        foreach (XElement characteristic in employee.Elements())
                        {
                            dt.Columns.Add(characteristic.Name.LocalName, typeof(string));
                        }
                        first = false;
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(employee.Elements().Select(x => (string)x).ToArray());

                }
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried importing this way but after the import none of the data columns are populated except the first and the first just says "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.String]"

Comment: I made a couple of minor updates just after I posted.  You are missing these updates especially the ToArray().